# What are some trends or interesting features you see in the following time series plot?

Tags: time-series, trend

[image: Time series plot of hourly temperature recorded of a city for a month]

This is a time series plot of hourly temperature recorded of a city for a month. I am unable to see any trends or cycles or other interesting features except the fact that it seems there was some type of discontinuity around 260-400 hour.

Please share any features/trends you see.

Comment: What is the question? What does the horizontal axis represent? Is this for homework?

Comment: There are too many possible answers, all of which are arguably "correct", since this calls for what each individual sees (like looking at clouds ... "*'tis like a camel, indeed*" / "*methinks it is like a weasel*"), rather than some reasonably objective criterion

Answer (score 0):

Only the data knows for sure  ! with apologies to Lamont Cranston . One would have to capture any ARIMA structure to be able to "SEE" other significant phenomenon like Pulses , Level Shifts, Seasonal Pulses , Local Time Trends , Change points in parameters over tine , Change points in model error variance over time , dependency between error variance and the level of the series etc...

If you post the data we can easily perform an analysis to suggest structure and violations thereof.

There might be hourly effects etc ... that once adjusted for might enable one to "SEE" better .